# Rudin's 'Principle of Mathematical Analysis' Problem 7.12

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $g$ and $f_n$ ($n = 1,2,\ldots$) are defined on $(0,\infty)$, are Riemann-integrable on $[t,T]$ whenever $0 < t < T < \infty$, $|f_n| \leq g$, $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $(0,\infty)$, and

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\,g(x)\,dx < \infty $$

Prove that

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\,\int_0^{\infty}\,f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^{\infty}\,f(x)\,dx $$

I appreciate all your comments, thanks.

Comment: Show that $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ exist, and show the convergence by splitting the domain into two parts. One where you get a small difference from the domination by $g$, and one where you use the compact convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than writing my solution on here, I think its best if I gave you the official answer from the solution manual.

The solution manual of "Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis" can be found here
http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009

I have also posted the answer to your question as an image below.

[image: Rudin 1]

[image: Rudin 2]

[image: Rudin 3]

The images above contain the solution. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Don't worry, this should be enough. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Your welcome :)