# Baby Rudin exercise 7.12

Tags: real-analysis

There is a standard solution posted for this problem(here is the link: [Rudin's 'Principle of Mathematical Analysis' Problem 7.12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801821/rudins-principle-of-mathematical-analysis-problem-7-12)). I understand everything except the last step(the inequality). I don't see why there exists an interval $[c,d]$ that the first term is less than $\varepsilon/3$ for all $n?$

Comment: If you understood the argument right above that wherein it discuss bounding the difference of integrals of $\phi$ for various choices of $\phi$, then you just take $\epsilon/3$ in that line rather than $\epsilon$.

Comment: I mean, there exists [c,d] for every n, but how do we guarantee that there is an interval [c,d] that exists for all n.( n approaches infinity. )

Comment: I think I got it now.. It is because of the dominance of g